# When sorting an array by an attribute, in the case of a tie how would I tell it to randomly select a tied record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a sort like this:

```
outfits = outfits.sort_by{|o| [o.total_non_black_listed_votes]}
```

where I'm sorting the outfits based on their votes. In the case of a tie, I would like to randomly select one of the tied records, rather than use another attribute for the secondary sort key. I'm not sure how I would go about this though.

Answer (score 3):

```
outfits.sort_by!{|o| [o.total_non_black_listed_votes, rand]}
```